# Getting subset of pixels of raster using ArcPy without Advanced license?

Tags: arcpy, raster, numpy

I am looking for a good solution to get a particular subset of raster pixels.
For example:

- I have raster 5x5
- I need to clip:

--column = 1

--row between 1 and 5

What will be the best method?

I was trying to get results using NumPy array by slicing it and exporting it back to raster.

I am wondering if there is much better way of doing it.

Here is my code. The problem is - I cannot export my numpy array slice  to raster, because it is a 1 dimentional array.

```
    import arcpy, numpy
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    raster_path = r'D:\raster.tif'
    raster = arcpy.Raster(raster_path)
    lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(raster.extent.XMin, raster.extent.YMin)

    raster_numpy = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(friction_raster_buffered_path, lowerLeft)
    x_length = raster_numpy.shape[0]
    print raster_numpy [0,1:x_length-1]
    arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(raster_numpy [0,1:x_length-1], lowerLeft, raster.meanCellHeight).save(r'd:\rstrLC.tif')
```

Error: ValueError: Argument in_array: A two or three dimensional NumPy array is required.

Comment: does it work? sorry for bad explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply reshape it to 2-D.  For instance:

`raster_numpy[0, 1:x_length-1].reshape(1, raster_numpy.shape[1] - 2)`

Also, if you wish to take column 0 and the inner rows, you need to slice it differently. I believe this is what you're looking for:

`raster_numpy[1:-1, 0].reshape(raster_numpy.shape[0] - 2, 1)`